# How to click below router link by using protractor

Tags: selenium, automation, protractor, end-to-end

I have trying to use protractor to test angular application. for below snippet i could not able to find a way to click it.

i am trying to click on route link

Complete code snippet

```
describe('Enter username and passord',   function () {
    it('should enter name as harish',  function () {
        browser.get('http://dev.policytracker.io');
        element(by.buttonText('Login')).click().then( function () {
            //browser.sleep(3000);
            element(by.name('username')).sendKeys('Harish.abc');
            browser.sleep(1000);
            element(by.name('Password')).sendKeys('rupesh');
            element(by.className('mat-raised-button')).click()
            browser.sleep(5000);
            //element(by.linkText('Calculators')).click();

            element(by.css('[routerlink="/notifications/notification"]')).click();

            //var byBranch = element(by.cssContainingText(".mat-list-item-content .font-size-xs > div", "Calculators"));
            //byBranch.click();


            //browser.waitForAngular();

        });

    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<mat-nav-list _ngcontent-c0="" class="mat-nav-list mat-list-base" role="navigation">
    <mat-list-item _ngcontent-c0="" class="text-color-light mdl-grid padding-lr-zero mat-list-item" routerlink="/notifications/notification" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="/notifications/notification">
        <div class="mat-list-item-content">
            <div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple="" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLElement]"></div>
            <div class="mat-list-text"></div>
            <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="text-align-center full-width  mdl-cell--hide-tablet mdl-cell--hide-phone">
                <mat-icon _ngcontent-c0="" class="mdl-grid margin-zero padding-zero mat-icon material-icons mat-icon-no-color" role="img" aria-hidden="true">notifications</mat-icon>
                <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="font-size-xs">Notifications</div>
            </div>
            <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="mdl-grid mdl-grid--no-spacing full-width mdl-cell--hide-desktop">
                <mat-icon _ngcontent-c0="" class="mdl-grid margin-zero padding-l-zero mdl-cell--middle mat-icon material-icons mat-icon-no-color" role="img" aria-hidden="true">notifications</mat-icon>
                <span _ngcontent-c0="" class="mdl-cell--middle">Notifications</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

**Error stack:**

```
Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
        at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
        at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
  Message:
    Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds
      (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.80)
    Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
    System info: host: 'MADAN-RAMINENI', ip: '10.0.75.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
  Stack:
    ScriptTimeoutError: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds
      (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.80)
    Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
    System info: host: 'MADAN-RAMINENI', ip: '10.0.75.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\madan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
        at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\madan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
        at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\madan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    From: Task: Protractor.waitForAngular() - Locator: By(css selector, [routerlink="/notifications/notification"])
        at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (C:\Users\madan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:807:17)
        at ProtractorBrowser.executeAsyncScript_ (C:\Users\madan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:425:28)
        at angularAppRoot.then (C:\Users\madan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:456:33)
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\madan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\madan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\madan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
        at asyncRun (C:\Users\madan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27)
        at C:\Users\madan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7Error
        at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\madan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:459:27)
        at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function).args [as click] (C:\Users\madan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:91:29)
        at ElementFinder.(anonymous function).args [as click] (C:\Users\madan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:831:22)
        at E:\Protractor POC\spec.js:13:75
        at elementArrayFinder_.then (C:\Users\madan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:804:32)
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\madan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\madan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\madan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
        at asyncRun (C:\Users\madan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27)
        at C:\Users\madan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
    From: Task: Run it("should enter name as harish") in control flow
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (C:\Users\madan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:94:19)
    From asynchronous test:
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (E:\Protractor POC\spec.js:2:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Protractor POC\spec.js:1:63)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 32.402 seconds
```

Comment: show your code trials and error you facing

Comment: Hi Dev **element(by.css('[routerlink="/notifications/notification"]')).click()** i am trying like this. i am very new to protractor

Comment: if i don't use click() the test case i passed. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
it('should enter name as harish',  async() => {
       await browser.get('http://dev.policytracker.io');
       await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);   
       await element(by.buttonText('Login')).click();
       await browser.sleep(3000);
       await element(by.name('username')).sendKeys('Harish.abc');
       await browser.sleep(1000);
       await element(by.name('Password')).sendKeys('rupesh');
       await element(by.className('mat-raised-button')).click();
       await browser.sleep(5000);
       await element(by.css('mat-nav-list>mat-list-item.text-color-light')).click();
        });
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Please increase the defaultTimeoutInterval